# I'm confused about decimals and total Supply with my erc20 token

Tags: solidity, contract-design, erc-20, decimals

I created erc20 token. I want total supply of 50,00,000.
And I want to give 7% tax on every transaction.
So if anyone sends single coin then, how can I get 7% and transfer remaining to receiver?
For this problem I decided to give 2 decimal places. I.e. value of decimals method I set 2.
So now
I should increase total supply by 2 zeros
Or what
I'm confused
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> 50,00,000

For clarity, I'll assume you meant for 50,000,000.

With two decimal places, add two more zeroes, so: 50,000,000.00 => 5000000000.

You still have the problem of indivisibility/precision at the low end, e.g. sending `1`. This just doesn't go away. You can and should decide what happens to rounding errors because they are unavoidable.

Hope it helps.